# How to remove hosts from zabbix template?

Tags: zabbix, template

I have removed a bunch of servers from a template, but all the items and triggers from the template remained in the server configurations.

**Questions**

1. Is there a way how to *unlink* hosts form a template and delete all it's items and triggers?
2. When I already did remove some hosts from a template, leaving all items and triggers in all affected hosts from the template, is there a way to remove them in some easy way? I cannot imagine doing it one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. the answer of @mschuett is correct. You should *Unlink and clear*.
2. to remove the untemplated items from your hosts, you can filter **on each host** by *Not templated items*, select all and delete.

If there are many hosts in that situation, it's better to create a group for all of them, select the Host group and filter again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

a) from the [manual](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/templates/linking):

> Choosing the Unlink option will simply remove association with the template, while leaving all its entities (items, triggers, graphs etc.) with the host.
>
> Choosing the Unlink and clear option will remove both the association with the template and all its entities (items, triggers, graphs etc.).

b) Not tested, but try to re-link the template and then `unlink and clear`.